# jquery post data to a php script and display it immediately in the same php script file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to post data to a php script (showitemid.php) using ajax and open the same script (showitemid.php) immediately in a thickbox on a hyperlink click and display that posted data. Below is my code:

**postitemid.php**

This file consists of multiple check-boxes. The user will tick the checkboxes and click a hyperlink. On clicking the hyperlink all the selected check-box values would be posted to showitemid.php and then immediately showitemid.php would open in a thickbox and display the received values. But it isn't receiving any values in my code ? Need help.

```
$('#showitem).click(function()
{
    var data = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function()   {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $.ajax({type: 'POST', 

             url: 'showitemid.php',
             data: data,success: success,dataType: dataType});
        });
```

**showitemid.php**

```
$data = ''; 

if (isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $data = $_POST['data'];
}
elseif (isset($_GET['data']))
{
    $data = $_GET['data'];
}


echo 'd='.$data;
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
  $('#showthickbox').click(function()
{
    var data = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function()   {
        return this.value;
    }).get();//your code

    $.post("showitemid.php",{data:data},function(data){
       $("#thickbox").html(data);
      }) 
    })
})
```

in your `showitemid.php`

```
echo "your data";
```

Comment: makes no sense to make 2 requests to same file...one with data, the other not. For `load()` version server won't know what data to populate

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the original code is the data being sent has no key named `data` to match `$_POST['data'])` so `$_POST['data'])` is empty. You have to send key/value pairs, you are only sending a value with no key. You are likely getting a bit confused since you use the same variable name constantly

```
var dataArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function()   {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

var dataToServer= { data : dataArray} /* now have the key to match $_REQUEST in php */
```

Now can use AJAX shorthand method `load()` to populate content

```
$('#myContainer').load( "yourfile.php", dataToServer, function(){
/* new html exists run open thickbox code here*/
})
```

Comment: sir, please can you provide the full code , how do i open the thickbox  and display the data

Comment: Follow the docs of the thickbox script. I have no idea what your html  looks like ( you never posted any) or what element contains the data and although I know Thickbox is a lightbox copycat I don't know where it comes from. Have you no working code for opening the thickbox plugin?

Comment: The code to show a thickbox is :  tb_show("Items","showitemid.php?&TB_iframe=true&height=120&width=400","/images/cart.jpg");

Comment: mycontainer in your code is on the same page , but i want it on a new thickbox window

Comment: i have just specified class="thickbox" and on clicking it the window opens. similarly in my jquery am using tb_show and it shows a popup window resembling lightbox

Comment: The plugin is no longer maintained and the website suggests using other plugins. Use colorbox...it has far more robust API. There are no docs on Thickbox site for programically opening modal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18675/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-charlietfl)